# Save previous preferences/choices using PHP

Tags: php

This is my first question here, probably a very simple one but I can't really find how to do it.

When I tried to google it, I only came across cookies and sessions, but I don't know how to use them, and was hoping there was a more simple way. I only started with PHP today.

On the following page I want the user to be able to switch background, text color, text decoration, etc. I got that to work as well, but I would love to find a way to save the previous choice, and add it to the next one.

So if someone picks a red background-color, it should not switch back to white when they pick another style, such as a black text color.

Is there a easy way (for starters like me) to fix this?

This is the site so far: http://mark.wigf7.sde.dk/PHP/opgave_g.php?baggrundfarve=FF8000

Comment: Welcome to SO, please make your question clearer; add code, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: The current way is already dead simple (you would agree if you had in mind all of the things that PHP sessions do automatically on your behalf). Just spend some more time with the language. :)

Comment: I don't normally recommend tutorials on _programming_ from about.com, but this is dead simple and is meant for beginners.  I think you'll find sessions to be easy to interface with if you just give it a little while and read this: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `$_SESSION` [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), first begin by adding this to the top of your PHP script(s):

```
session_start();
```

Then you can store data in `$_SESSION` and access it later.

```
//Store user's selection
$_SESSION['bg_color'] = $bg_color_choice;
```

On next page:

```
//Use default of #FFFFFF unless user made selection.
$bg_color = isset($_SESSION['bg_color']) ? $_SESSION['bg_color'] : '#FFFFFF';
```

**EDIT**: Since you linked to the page you'll be using:

```
$allowedColors = array(
    'FFFFFF',
    'D8D8D8',
    '000000'
);

if(isset($_GET['baggrundfarve']) && in_array($_GET['baggrundfarve'], $allowedColors)){
    $_SESSION['bg_color'] = $_GET['baggrundfarve'];
}
```

Comment: It is all on one page, will that still work?
http://mark.wigf7.sde.dk/PHP/opgave_g.php?baggrundfarve=FF8000

Comment: @user1765065 If it's all on one page (without form submission), you'll need to use JavaScript, simply because PHP is a server-side language, whereas JavaScript is client-side.

Comment: Thank's for the very fast responces, i will try to look into how i should add those codes. It's all abit blurry for me still, but i'm sure it will be allright later :P